# Data row pulled from SQL Server with pyodbc is an "unhashable type"

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, pyodbc

I'm currently querying data from MS SQL Server 2008 based on user input. However, I am getting an error when I am trying to get the five number summary using the describe() function.

```
import pyodbc
import numpy as np
import pandas.io.sql as sql
import pandas

print "What Part Number will you examine?"
PartN = raw_input()

conn = pyodbc.connect('my connection info')
curs = conn.cursor()
sqlr = """SELECT partmadeperhour FROM Completions WHERE  PartNumber = ?  
AND endtime > '2012-12-31 23:59:00' ORDER BY partmadeperhour"""


q = curs.execute(sqlr,[PartN]).fetchall()

df = pandas.DataFrame(q, columns =['rate'])
print df



columnnames = list(df.columns.values)
print columnnames

df['rate'].describe()
```

My data frame looks something like this

```
       rate
0      [0.25]
1      [0.67]
2      [0.93]
...       ...
1474   [5400.00]
```

And I am getting the following return and error:

```
[1475 rows x 1 columns]
['rate']
rate    object
dtype: object
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "newr.py", line 30, in <module>
    df['rate'].describe()

 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4034, in describe
return describe_1d(self, percentiles)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4031, in describe_1d
return describe_categorical_1d(data)

    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", 
line 4007, in describe_categorical_1d
objcounts = data.value_counts()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 433, in value_counts
normalize=normalize, bins=bins, dropna=dropna)

 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 245, in value_counts
keys, counts = htable.value_count_object(values, mask)

 File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 983, in pandas.hashtable.value_count_object 
(pandas\hashtable.c:17616)

 File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 994, in pandas.hashtable.value_count_object 
(pandas\hashtable.c:17353)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'pyodbc.Row'
```

I understand that I need to convert the data in the dataframe to a different type as its currently an object, but not sure of how to convert to a float.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure you're using pandas 0.12 or later:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> pandas.__version__
'0.14.1'
```

Use [pandas.read_sql_query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas.read_sql_query) to populate the dataframe directly, passing the query string and pyodbc connection. Note that the column alias `rate` is added to the T-SQL query, since `pandas.read_sql_query` doesn't support passing a list or dictionary of column names:

```
...
>>> sql = "select 0.25 union select 0.67 union select 0.93 as rate" 
>>> df = pandas.read_sql_query(sql, connection)
>>> df
   rate
0  0.25
1  0.67
2  0.93
>>> df['rate'].describe()
count    3.000000
mean     0.616667
std      0.343123
min      0.250000
25%      0.460000
50%      0.670000
75%      0.800000
max      0.930000
dtype: float64
```

The parameter values in your original query can be supplied using the `params` parameter of `pandas.read_sql_query`.

Comment: Am I correct that with pandas.read_sql_query I need to use SQLAlchemy in lieu of pyodbc?

Comment: No, SQLAlchemy isn't needed. The DBAPI-compliant pyodbc connection works just fine.

Comment: Thank you, your solution made this much easier than I expected it would be.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
q = curs.execute(sqlr,[PartN]).fetchall()
df = pandas.DataFrame(q, columns =['rate'])
```

can you try

```
df = sql.read_frame(sqlr, conn) # You can directly read a table as dataframe
```

Comment: Note that `read_frame` is deprecated, use `pd.read_sql` or `pd.read_sql_query` instead.